# How can I check colors of all inputs

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I check colors of all inputs, if some colors of inputs are done by attribute style "color" and another inputs done by a CSS style?

Comment: Are you using Selenium IDE or Selenium-Webdriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use Java Robot's [getPixelColor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#getPixelColor%28int,%20int%29) method.

Or, the preferred way, using JavaScript, [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) + [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration#Methods)

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I know, how to check color of 1 input: "assertEval | window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]).getPropertyValue('color') | rgb(0, 0, 0), but How can I check color of all inputs?